# Create Buttons from the objects, with same action for each of them. Get name pressed button

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Trying to make something like a clothing manager addon for myself.
Easy to add, enable and disable objects.
I'm not sure if this is the right way, because I can't get which button is pressed. But I don't even know what exactly I should be looking at to solve this.

**draw:**

```
    def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
    col = layout.column(align=False)

    layout.operator( "add.select")
    
    layout.label(text=" Outfit List:")
    SCENE_OBJ = bpy.context.scene.objects
    for tmp_obj in SCENE_OBJ:
        if tmp_obj.type == 'MESH':
            if ".mf1t." in tmp_obj.name:
                if ".mf1t.active" in tmp_obj.name:
                    layout.operator("on.off", text=tmp_obj.data.name, text_ctxt='hoho', depress=True)
                if ".mf1t.null" in tmp_obj.name:
                    layout.operator("on.off", text=tmp_obj.data.name, text_ctxt='haha', depress=False)
```

**operator:**

```
class op_add (bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "add.select"
bl_label = "Add to List"

def execute(self, context):
    CS_OBJ = bpy.context.selected_objects
    
    for tmp_obj in CS_OBJ:
        if tmp_obj.type == 'MESH':
            if ".mf1t." not in tmp_obj.name:
                tmp_obj.name = tmp_obj.name + ".mf1t.active"

class op_on_off (bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "on.off"
bl_label = "On / Off"

def execute(self, context):
    if context.window_manager:
        if ".mf1t.active" in tmp_obj.name:
            tmp_obj.name = tmp_obj.name.replace("active", "null")
        if ".mf1t.null" in tmp_obj.name:
            tmp_obj.name = tmp_obj.name.replace("null", "active")
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------**

I'll post my result here. Perhaps this will help someone, but Marty answer is already pretty clear.
**Result (Thank to [Marty Fouts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/42221/marty-fouts)):**

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "On/Off Manager Explain",
    "description" : "A demonstration addon (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252081/create-buttons-from-the-objects-with-same-action-for-each-of-them-get-name-pre)",
    "author" : "Marty Fouts and duales",
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252081/create-buttons-from-the-objects-with-same-action-for-each-of-them-get-name-pre",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class op_add_exp(Operator):
    bl_idname = "op.add"
    bl_label = "Add to Global"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def execute(self, context):
        for tmp_obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if tmp_obj.type == 'MESH':
                if ".mf1t." not in tmp_obj.name:
                    tmp_obj.name = tmp_obj.name + ".mf1t.active"

        return {'FINISHED'}

class op_on_off_exp(Operator):
    """ tooltip goes here """
    bl_idname = "op.on_off"
    bl_label = "Foo Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    foo : StringProperty(name="foo", description="foobar")
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        for tmp_obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            if ".mf1t.active" in tmp_obj.name:
                if tmp_obj.name == self.foo:
                    tmp_obj.name = tmp_obj.name.replace("active", "null")
                    tmp_obj.hide_viewport = True
                    tmp_obj.hide_render = True
            elif ".mf1t.null" in tmp_obj.name:
                if tmp_obj.name == self.foo:
                    tmp_obj.name = tmp_obj.name.replace("null", "active")
                    tmp_obj.hide_viewport = False
                    tmp_obj.hide_render = False

        return {'FINISHED'}

class panel_manager_exp(Panel):
    """Display test button twice. Invoke it with different arguments"""
    bl_label = "On/Off Manager Exp"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator(op_add_exp.bl_idname, text="Add Selected OBJ")
        self.layout.label(text="Added Object List")
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        for tmp_obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            if tmp_obj.type == 'MESH':
                if ".mf1t." in tmp_obj.name:
                    if ".mf1t.active" in tmp_obj.name:
                        prop = col.operator(op_on_off_exp.bl_idname, text=tmp_obj.data.name, depress=True).foo=tmp_obj.name
                    if ".mf1t.null" in tmp_obj.name:
                        prop = col.operator(op_on_off_exp.bl_idname, text=tmp_obj.data.name, depress=False).foo=tmp_obj.name

classes = [
    op_on_off_exp,
    op_add_exp,
    panel_manager_exp,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

And in the end you will be able to do something like this. Simple but convenient.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single operator to respond differently to different buttons, one way to do this is to give the operator a class variable.  Then, when you create the buttons in the panel, you set the class variable.  This example adds a variable `foo` to a simple operator class and then calls the class `execute` function through the panel with `bar` or `hah` depending on which button is pushed in the panel.  It takes advantage of the fact that the UI `operator` function returns a pointer to the operator's data and Python syntax allows the pointer to be used at the call site.  In this example the `execute` routine just prints the value of `foo`.  You can use it how you would like.

```py
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name" : "multiple buttons",
    "description" : "A demonstration addon",
    "author" : "Marty",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.props import StringProperty


class TLA_OT_operator(Operator):
    """ tooltip goes here """
    bl_idname = "demo.operator"
    bl_label = "I'm a Skeleton Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    foo : StringProperty(name="foo", description="foobar")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):

        self.report({'INFO'},
            f"execute() foo = {self.foo}")

        return {'FINISHED'}


class TLA_PT_sidebar(Panel):
    """Display test button twice. Invoke it with different arguments"""
    bl_label = "buttons"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TLA"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        prop = col.operator(TLA_OT_operator.bl_idname, text="This is bar").foo="bar"
        prop = col.operator(TLA_OT_operator.bl_idname, text="This is hah").foo="hah"
 
classes = [
    TLA_OT_operator,
    TLA_PT_sidebar,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)


def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: `foo` is a class member (or member variable, not just a variable), in this case a string property.

Comment: Yes, I said that.  Perhaps too indirectly, but "you give the operator a class variable" and "adds a variable foo to..." implies that foo is a class variable in an operator class. Still I can make it clearer.

Comment: Thank You so much. <3
I already did something similar with enum, but enum is not so convenient to use.
That solve all what i try to do.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. I look forward to seeing what you accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want to do. I "stole" it from here: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/calling-functions-by-pressing-buttons-in-blender-custom-ui/

```
bl_info = {
  "name": "Multiple operator example",
  "author": "Ibraheem",
  "version": (1, 0),
  "blender": (2, 80, 0),
  "location": "View3D > Sidebar > My own addon",
  "description": "Example with multiple operators",
  "warning": "",
  "wiki_url": "",
  "category": "3D View"}
 
import bpy
 
 
class EXAMPLE_OT_func_1(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "do.func_1"
  bl_label = "Lay Ground"
 
  def execute(self, context):
    # Implement your first function here
    self.report({'INFO'}, f"This is {self.bl_idname}")
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    return {'FINISHED'}
 
 
class EXAMPLE_OT_func_2(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "example.func_2"
  bl_label = "Function 2"
 
  def execute(self, context):
    # Implement your second function here
    self.report({'INFO'}, f"This is {self.bl_idname}")
    return {'FINISHED'}
 
 
class Function3_delete_selected_object(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "do.delete_obj"
  bl_label = "Function 3"
 
  def execute(self, context):
    # Implement your third function here
    obj = context.active_object
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
    self.report({'INFO'}, f"This is {self.bl_idname}")
    return {'FINISHED'}
 
 
class EXAMPLE_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
  bl_label = "MAP MAKER"
  bl_category = "M_M"
  bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
  bl_region_type = "UI"
 
  def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout     
    obj=context.active_object
    if obj:
      layout.row().label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
      layout.row().prop(obj, "name")
    layout.operator(EXAMPLE_OT_func_1.bl_idname)
    layout.operator(EXAMPLE_OT_func_2.bl_idname)
    layout.operator(Function3_delete_selected_object.bl_idname)
 
     
 
 
classes = (EXAMPLE_OT_func_1, EXAMPLE_OT_func_2, Function3_delete_selected_object, EXAMPLE_PT_panel)
 
 
def register():
  for cls in classes:
    bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
 
 
def unregister():
  for cls in classes:
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

Comment: It's not what the OP should do.  It's not even the solution to what they are trying to do, which is to have a single operator that is informed of which button was pressed.